# How to launch qt application with the command window in minimized state, without any flicker?

Tags: qt

I am working on VS2005 sp2, with qt3.3.7. I have set the linkers>system>subsystem to Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE) as I need the command window to check runtime status of my project at runtime.

I want to launch my application with the command window minimized. The problem is, whenever my application launches, the command window comes in maximize state.

If I minimize this window using :

```
HWND hWnd = GetConsoleWindow();    
ShowWindow( hWnd, SW_MINIMIZE );
```

still I get a flicker, ie for a split second the command window opens and then minimizes.

How can I launch my qt application with the command window in minimized state, without any flicker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is launching your own console process using `CreateProcess()` with `startupInfo.wShowWindow=SW_SHOWMINIMIZED`, and `startupInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW | STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;` setting `startupInfo.hStdOutput` to a handle you can use for output.  I've tried launching `cmd.exe` like this, and while I can get it to start minimized, I haven't managed to write to it.  I don't have any more time to play with it tonight, if you manage it I'd like to see the solution!